# Is an Expected Value Fixed or Random

Tags: random-variable, expected-value

Suppose I have a random variable, x, and then let E(x) = p denote its expected value. I believe p can be treated as non-stochastic (fixed), but the variable x obviously cannot.

Is that assumption correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can. Recall the definition of the expected value (in the continuous case) of a random variable having density $f(x)$,
$$
E(X)=\int xf(x)dx.
$$
So, heuristically, what is random ($X$) has been averaged over in the expected value. Or, while the particular realization of a random variable is uncertain ex ante, the value we expect it to take is not.